# Laravel SQL Error: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app I'm gtting the following error, I think it's because the relation is incorrectly formed?

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `badges` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `user_badge` on `users`.`id` = `user_badge`.`user_id` where `badges`.`id` = `user_badge`.`badge_id` and `id` = 1) and `badgecategory_id` = 4 limit 1)\
```

Method triggering the error.

```
public function syncBadges(Request $request)
    {

        $user = User::with('badges')->findOrFail($request['user_id']);

        $badge = Badge::whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('id' , $request['user_id']);
        })
        ->where('badgecategory_id',$request['badgecategory_id'])
        ->first();

        if($badge)
        {
            $user->badges()->dettach($badge['id']);
            $user->badges()->attach($request['badge_id']);
        }
        else
        {
            $user->badges()->attach($request['badge_id']);
        }
}
```

User Model:

```
public function badges()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Badge', 'user_badge', 'user_id', 'badge_id');
    }
```

Badge Model:

```
protected $table = 'badges';

public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'user_badge', 'badge_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\BadgeCategory', 'badgecategory_id');
    }
```

Bage table migration

```
public function up()
    {


        Schema::create('badges', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('badgecategory_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('badgecategory_id')->references('id')->on('badgecategories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('icon')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });


    }
```

User Badge Pivot table migration

```
class CreateUserBadgeTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {


        Schema::create('user_badge', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('badge_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->foreign('badge_id')->references('id')->on('badges')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


    }

    
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_badge');
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
    }
}
```

Comment: the `whereHas` is doing a join so `id` is ambiguous, it doesn't know which table you are referring to when you want `id` since both tables have an `id` field

Comment: How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

in your badge query you need to specify the table since you're using whereHas

```
$badge = Badge::whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('users.id' , $request['user_id']);
    })
    ->where('badgecategory_id',$request['badgecategory_id'])
    ->first();
```